# How to deal with legacy data that has a numeric row number suffix on the end of each field name

Tags: database, data-structures, datagrid

Say I already have a system that stores data in a database using the following format for the cell 'field name'. The data is represented in a table in the UI.

```
ColumnA1, ColumnB1, ColumnC1
ColumnA2, ColumnB2, ColumnC2
```

E.g. the data saved against ColumnA1 represents the value in the first column on the first row, the data saved in ColumnA2 the first column in the second row and so on. In the database you essentially have a simple 'data' table of key/value pairs (so only two columns: 'FieldName','Value').

In the UI this enables cells to be represented by simple text entry fields laid out in a grid which are repeated for each row. Because of the row suffix the field names are all unique so there is no need for anything more complicated (e.g. a 'datagrid'). This facilitates laying the UI out easily and also creating simple templates for representing the data (e.g. for printing / saving as a PDF), although obviously results in some repetition for each row.

Now imagine if more 'advanced' features are required allowing the data to be manipulated such as copying rows, adding rows, moving rows with drag and drop etc. Managing the field name row number suffixes is cumbersome and you are much better off changing the data structure to have the same field name for every row and add an additional property in the database for the 'row number'.

This would also work much better with pre-built 'data grid' UI components.

The problem is you have legacy data stored in the old format. There are a few possibilities for overcoming this:

1. Convert all the existing data into the new format in the database
2. Only do this for new data and have a flag that tells the system whether to use the legacy data structure and UI, or the new one.
3. Continue with the current format and have a 'converter' type of mechanism that converts the field names when data is loaded from or saved to the database.

I'm thinking option 2 is the way to go for performance, backwards compatibility and avoiding large-scale manipulation of existing data. What do you think and can you see any alternatives?